# python: exclude string regular expression

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to build a web scraper to get prices off http://fetch.co.uk/dogs/dog-food?per-page=20

I have the code here below:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen(url above)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

wrapList = bsObj.findAll("",{"class": re.compile("shelf-product__self.*")})
for wrap in wrapList:
    print(wrap.find("",{"itemprop": re.compile("shelf-product__price.*(?!cut).*")}).get_text())
    print(wrap.find("",{"class": re.compile("shelf-product__title.*")}).get_text())
```

In every wrap, there are sometimes 2 different prices and I am trying to exclude the cut price and get only the price below that one (the promo price).

i cannot figure out how to exclude the price with cut, the expression above does not work.

```
"shelf-product__price shelf-product__price--cut [ v2 ]"
"shelf-product__price shelf-product__price--promo [ v2 ]"
```

I have used the workaround below but i'd like to understand what i am getting wrong in the regular expression. sorry if the code is not pretty, i'm learning

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen(url above)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

wrapList = bsObj.findAll("",{"class": re.compile("shelf-product__self.*")})
for wrap in wrapList:
    print(wrap.find("",{"itemprop": re.compile("price.*")}).get_text())
    print(wrap.find("",{"class": re.compile("shelf-product__title.*")}).get_text())
```

Comment: the mentioned URl doesn't seems to have any element with `itemprop="shelf-product__price shelf-product__price--cut [ v2 ]"` the value for `itemprop` is either `title` or `price`. That's why the second regex with `price.*` is working.

Comment: @mchackam: it's indeed the `class` attribute and not the `itemprop` attribute, but it isn't the only problem. When an attribute has several values separated by spaces, the condition is tested on each value separately until one succeeds *(and not on the whole attribute)*. In any cases, the regex is wrong and using regex isn't the good approach here, it's easier to use a function as condition. As an aside putting a pattern compilation in a loop will slow down the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems. The first is that `.*(?!cut).*` is equivalent to `.*`. This is because the first `.*` consumes all of the remaining characters. Then of course the `(?!cut)` check passes since it's at the end of the string. Finally `.*` consumes 0 characters. So it's always a match. This regex would give you false positives. The only reason it gives you nothing is that you are looking in `itemprop` when the text you're looking for is in `class`.

Your workaround looks good to me. But if you wanted to base your search on classes I would do it like this.

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://fetch.co.uk/dogs/dog-food?per-page=20')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

wrapList = bsObj.findAll("",{"class": "shelf-product__self"})

def is_price(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and \
           'shelf-product__price' in tag['class'] and \
           'shelf-product__price--cut' not in tag['class']

for wrap in wrapList:
    print(wrap.find(is_price).text)
    x=wrap.find("",{"class": "shelf-product__title"}).get_text()
```

Regular expressions are fine but I think it's easier to do boolean logic with booleans.

Comment: You can avoid the first regex too.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use that complex code you may try below- `span[itemprop=price]` means select all `span` that have properties `itemprop` is `price`.

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get possible list of urls
urls = ['http://fetch.co.uk/dogs/dog-food?per-page=%s'%n for n in range(1,100)]

for url in urls:
  html = urlopen(url)
  bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
  for y in [i.text for i in bsObj.select("span[itemprop=price]")]:
    print y.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: It seems reasonable to use select but there are a few issues with the code. It uses python2 where the question uses python3. It tries different per-page values and i'm not sure why (it's not a page number). `respons.content` should be `html`.  `[t for t in ..]` does nothing. Also the price should be associated with the product name. That last point might prevent you from using select.